# Drools rule not true, how to use 'and'?

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine, rule, drools-planner

I'm trying to have the following working:

```
rule "userCount"
    when
        $user : User()
        $minutes : Integer()
            from accumulate(
                            MinutesPerUser( user == $user, $time : time) 
                            and Time(this == $time),
                            sum(1)
                           )
    then
        System.out.println( $minutes );
end
```

but it seems the `and Time(this == $user)` part is never true. If I remove that part I get some println output.

What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the relation of the Java classes, it's a little difficult to state definite facts. But from

```
 $user : User()
 //...
 and Time(this == $user),
```

it is quite evident that Time must be a superclass of User or vice versa: otherwise there's no way this constraint can be fulfilled.

I don't know what you should write instead, as there's no specification of what should be done.

BTW, `sum(1)` looks rather fishy, because that would be better expressed by `count(1)`, producing the same result.

Comment: Argh, forgive me laune, I had a typo in my code. $time is what I had in my production code, I just left a "debug" typo in there :(

Comment: Now we're going to need a set of facts - i.e., the code inserting it into working memory - that should produce a match. You should add this code to your Q.